# do i need ssl on my webserver for my android app

Tags: android, ssl

Is it a requirement to install SSL on my webserver in order for my Android app to communicate with my MySQL database? Im having some errors communicating with it and im wondering if this may be the issue.

Comment: It is not a requirement, but generally speaking it is a good idea to implement, considering security. Post code to see if we can find the real problem.

Comment: her @edwardmp heres a new link to a new question with the code to this error, i had my question answered for the title so i thought it would be wise to just open a new question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267965/java-net-unknownhostexception-unable-to-resolve-host Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it isn't, as far as I'm aware. I'd recommend it if you are handling sensitive information, though. I assume you're calling some script (probably php?) server side and using it to connect to the database. All you would do is use something like a httpClient and request the page from the server.

Can you further clarify on the error you're getting?

Comment: I'll be more then happy to open up a new post about the error im receiving, i however dont want to post it here. Due to the fact that this was just a general question about SSL. If you would be so kind to check out my profile soon to see the new question with errors i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: here is the follow up question to this error. Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267965/java-net-unknownhostexception-unable-to-resolve-host