# java.net.unknownhostexception unable to resolve host

Tags: php, android, httpclient

Ive just been trying to get a simple login script working, my PHP is out of date its crappy, but i have an iOS version of this same app that works fine logging in, i know nothings wrong with my php scripts, and i need them to stay the same, or i suppose i could create a new one intitled `android_login.php` but lets work with what i got for now.

My error is common, but i have tried all the common fixes, including recreating VDM device, and even now using my physical phone to test. My phones outputting `java.net.unknownhostexception unable to resolve host` **into my `et_un` TextEdit** heres my code

I am including the following into the `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

heres my LoginActivity.java **UPDATED**

```
package com.example.atmebeta;


import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    EditText un,pw;
    TextView error;
    Button ok;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        un=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_un);
        pw=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_pw);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        error=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_error);

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                RequestParams parameters = new RequestParams();
                parameters.put("email", un.getText().toString());
                parameters.put("password", pw.getText().toString());
                client.get("http://www.thatonewebsite.com/login.php", parameters, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    public final void onSuccess(String response) {
                        error.setText("Correct Username or Password");
                    }

                    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
                        error.setText("Sorry!! Incorrect Username or Password");
                    } 
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

the login.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#DDDDDD"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_un"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
         android:text="User Name:"
         android:textColor="#444444"
         android:textSize="10pt" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/et_un"
         android:layout_width="150dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/et_pw"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tv_un"
         android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
         android:ems="10" />

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/et_pw"
         android:layout_width="150dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/tv_pw"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
         android:ems="10"
         android:password="true" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_pw"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_below="@+id/et_un"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
         android:text="Password:"
         android:textColor="#444444"
         android:textSize="10pt" />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btn_login"
         android:layout_width="100dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_centerVertical="true"
         android:text="Login" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tv_error"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="40dip"
         android:layout_below="@+id/btn_login"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
         android:textColor="#AA0000"
         android:textSize="7pt" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and if its needed the login.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET["email"])  && isset($_GET["password"]) ){
                $email = $_GET["email"];
                $password = $_GET["password"];
                $result = login( $email, $password);
                echo $result;
                }

function makeSqlConnection()
{
$DB_Host = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "bdname";
$DB_User = "dbuser"; 
$DB_Pass = "dbpass";

    $con = mysql_connect($DB_Host,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error()); 

        mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

    return $con;
}

function disconnectSqlConnection($con)
{
    mysql_close($con);
}

function login($eMail, $password)
{
    //require (FILE);
    $con = makeSqlConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$eMail' AND password = '$password'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    $res1 = mysql_num_rows($res);

    disconnectSqlConnection($con);

     if ($res1 != 0) {
        return $fetch['email'];
    }else{
        return 0;
    }// end else


}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might seem radical but throw out your CustomHttpClient.java and start using a library such as [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). I would be very surprised if you still had the problem after switching to a library that takes care of all that stuff for you. Example:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
rp.put("email", un.getText().toString());
rp.put("password", pw.getText().toString());
client.post("http://www.mywebsite.com/thatoneloginscript.php", rp, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public final void onSuccess(String response) {
        // handle your response here
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
        // something went wrong
    }               
});
```

Comment: Im trying to look for a solution without JSON

Comment: Android Async Http Client can use JSON if you want to, but you don't have to. I'll update with a simple example.

Comment: Thank you very much was not aware of that at all.

Comment: For some reason when im using your code its not giving me the same error anymore but it is saying thats its logging in even thought im clearly typing in a false email and password. any ideas?

Comment: btw i did change the client.`post` to client.`get` to see if that would make a difference since im logging in but still nothing... although... i imagine `POST` is the proper way

Comment: Ah, sorry, in your PHP code you do $_GET and that means that you should do an HTTP GET from the client side. Either you change the client side to do client.get() instead of client.post() or you change your PHP to $_POST or $_REQUEST (to catch both GET and POST params)

Comment: but i tried the client.get method and it didnt work... i'll try the request

Comment: Hmm, I suggest that you debug your serverside code. Print the entire contents of $_REQUEST, print_r($_REQUEST). Using that output it should be very clear what content you get from the client and if it's GET or POST data.

Comment: I got everything working, needed a few if and else statements and some php errors, needed to change my result in the php to return a string and not a int. Thanks for all the help.